# $j$-fold summation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, linear-programming

I need a fast way (closed form would be better) to calculate 
$ S=\sum_{a_{1}=1}^{a_{1}=c}\sum_{a_{2}=a_{1}}^{a_{2}=c}\dots\sum_{a_{j}=a_{j-1}}^{a_{j}=c}1$. 
I derived this from 
$S=\sum_{a_{1}\leq c}\sum_{a_{2}\leq c}\dots\sum_{a_{j}\leq c}\mathbf{1}_{1\leq a_{1}\leq a_{2}\leq\dots\leq a_{j}\leq c}$.

I got the latter relation from doing some work in marginalizing a pdf.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{m-1+k}{m} = \binom{m+n}{m+1}.$ This is sometimes called [*Christmas stocking theorem*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristmasStockingTheorem.html), and is easily proved using Pascal's triangle.

Comment: I am really not able to use the hint. Please elaborate.

Comment: What do you get when $m = 0$? Then what do you get when $m=1$? You can recursively use this identity to simplify your sum by notincing that $$ S = \sum_{a_n = 1}^{c} \sum_{a_{n-1} = 1}^{a_n} \cdots \sum_{a_1 = 1}^{a_2} 1 = \sum_{a_n = 1}^{c} \sum_{a_{n-1} = 1}^{a_n} \cdots \sum_{a_1 = 1}^{a_2} \binom{a_1-1}{0}. $$